# Flask backend is queing requests

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, flask

The following backend API works perfectly fine, but I discovered today, that if a second user asks a question in my frontend, the request seems to be queued, as the response is not generated until the first one is completely finished.

```
@app.route('/regulatory_dossier', methods=['POST'])
def regulatory_dossier():
    """
    Endpoint to generate tokens based on a prompt for HR Documents

    Returns:
        Response: Response object containing generated tokens.

    """
    if authenticate_request():
        prompt = request.json.get("prompt", "What are argenx values?")
        chat_history = request.json.get("chat_history", "")
        username = request.json.get("username", "")      
        #tc.track_trace(f"Generating tokens for HR prompt: {prompt}")
        inputs = [item.get('input') for item in chat_history]
        outputs = [item.get('output') for item in chat_history]


        def generate_tokens():
            g = regulatory_dossier_gpt_chain(prompt, username, inputs, outputs)
            try:
                while True:
                    token = next(g)
                    yield token
            except StopIteration:
                pass
        return Response(stream_with_context(generate_tokens()), mimetype='text/event-stream')
    else:
        #tc.track_trace("Unauthorized request.")
        return jsonify({"error": "Unauthorized. Invalid or missing API key."}), 401


def regulatory_dossier_gpt_chain(prompt, username, inputs, outputs):
    """
    Start a new thread to generate tokens for regulatory dossier.

    Args:
        prompt (str): Prompt for the language model.

    Returns:
        ThreadedGenerator: ThreadedGenerator instance for token generation.

    """
    g = ThreadedGenerator()  # Initialize ThreadedGenerator
    # Start a new thread to run llm_thread_hrgpt function
    threading.Thread(target=llm_thread_regulatory_dossier_gpt, args=(g, prompt, username, inputs, outputs)).start()
    return g  # Return the ThreadedGenerator instance


def llm_thread_regulatory_dossier_gpt(g, prompt, username, inputs, outputs):
    """
    A function to run the language model in a separate thread.

    Args:
        g (ThreadedGenerator): ThreadedGenerator instance for token generation.
        prompt (str): Prompt for the language model.

    """
    try:
        # Initialize AzureChatOpenAI instance for interaction with OpenAI model
        chat = AzureChatOpenAI(
            azure_endpoint=SHD_AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT,
            openai_api_version="2023-03-15-preview",
            deployment_name=REG_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT,
            openai_api_key=SHD_OPENAI_KEY,
            openai_api_type="Azure",
            model_name=REG_OPENAI_GPT_MODEL_NAME,
            streaming=True,
            callbacks=[ChainStreamHandler(g)],  # Set ChainStreamHandler as callback
            temperature=0)
        
        # Define system and human message prompts
        messages = [
            SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(ANSWER_PROMPT_REG_DOSSIER),
            HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{question} Please answer in html format"),
        ]
        
        # Set up embeddings, vector store, chat prompt, retriever, memory, and chain
        embeddings = setup_embeddings()
        vector_store = setup_vector_store(embeddings, "vector-regulatorydossier-qa","vector-regulatorydossier-qa-semantic-configuration")
        chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages)
        retriever = ArgenxUserRetrieverDossier(vectorstore=vector_store, username=username)
        memory = setup_memory()
        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            questions = {'input': inputs[i]}
            answers = {'output': outputs[i]}
            memory.save_context(questions, answers)
        chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(chat, 
            retriever=retriever, 
            memory=memory, 
            verbose=False, 
            combine_docs_chain_kwargs={
                "prompt": chat_prompt, 
                "document_prompt": PromptTemplate(
                    template=DOCUMENT_PROMPT_DOSSIER,
                    input_variables=["page_content", "source"]
                )
            }
        )
        chain.run(prompt,callbacks=[PrintRetrievalHandler(g)])
    finally:
        # Close the generator after use
        g.close()
```

and then from vue I consume it like this:

```
async sendDossierMessage(messageToSend, botName) {
     const path = `localhost/regulatory_dossier`;
      
      console.log("Sending message:", messageToSend);
      // Retrieve current chat from Vuex store
      const currentChat = this.$store.state.currentChat;

      // Filter out only user messages to use as questions
      const questions = currentChat.filter((msg, index) => msg.sender === 'user' && index % 2 === 0);

      // Filter out only bot messages to use as answers
      const answers = currentChat.filter((msg, index) => msg.sender === botName && index % 2 === 1);

      questions.pop();
      //answers.pop();

      // Merge questions and answers into chat history format
      const chatHistory = questions.map((question, index) => {
        return { input: question.content, output: [answers[index].content] };
      });

      const requestBody = {
        prompt: messageToSend,
        chat_history: chatHistory, // Assuming this.chatHistory contains the chat history in the required format
        username: this.$store.state.claims.find(claim => claim.claim === 'email').value // Replace "your_username" with the actual username
      };

      const response = await fetch(path, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-API-Key': ''
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
      });
      const reader = response.body.getReader();
    
      const initialanswerPayload = {
        content: '',
        sender: botName,
        receiver: 'user',
        time: util.formatDate.format(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss'),
        isNewMessage: true
      };
      
      this.$store.commit('APPEND_MESSAGE_CHUNK', initialanswerPayload);
      let responseContent = ''; 
      let sourcesDetected = false; // Flag to indicate if sources section has been detected
      let skipRendering = false; // Flag to indicate whether to skip rendering
      let documents= ''
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-constant-condition
      while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader.read();
        if (done) break;
    
        const chunk = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(value);
```